# "a list of vectors of ints" - is this possible?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to use template within a template, a list can be a list of anythings and a string can be a string of anythings, so can I have a list of strings of some other type, for example int?

The first thing that came to mind:

```
std::list<std::vector<int>> listOfVectorsOfIntegers;
```

Sadly, it failed, so I wonder, is there a way to legally do this?

Edit: Sorry, I wasn't actually using string in my case, just typed it for a random container without considering it is not a template. In my case the problem was using >> instead of > >, adding an empty space fixes it.

Comment: What's an idea to create string of ints? Also add space in `>>` to look like `> >` because C++ interprets `>>` as biteshift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` is not a class template itself

You probably want one of these:

```
std::list<std::vector<int>>   a;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> b;
std::list<std::list<int>>     c;
```

In C++03, and C++98, the `>>` should be separated by space; in C++11, there is no such need.

Comment: If he write in C++03 not in C++11 then it will fail again.

Comment: you forget std::vector<std::list<int>> d; also the second "std::" in all of the examples...

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: Oops. Fixed it now.

Comment: @Hauleth Why would you think that?

Comment: Cause of right angle bracket error http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket

Comment: @Hauleth C++03 is so yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<std::basic_string<int> > listOfStringsOfIntegers;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is not a template class. It is a typedef for a specific instantiation of a template class: it is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. If you want a string of an int type, you'd use `std::basic_string<int>`. (I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it's possible.)

And don't forget to insert a space between `>` and `>` to prevent it from being parsed as the `>>` operator.

```
std::list<std::basic_string<int> > listOfStringsOfIntegers;
```

Comment: +1 But `>>` is usually correctly parsed by compilers nowadays.

Comment: "Correctly" in the sense that the error message explains that a space needs to be inserted, for me. Yes, C++11 changes that, but the compiler I'm using defaults to C++03 rules.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this mind explaining what's wrong with this answer -- based on what the question was when I answered?

Answer (score 0):

std::string is not a template class, you probably want std::vector or std::list instead. But the answer is yes.

You can have such a declaration:

`std::list<std::list<int> > myList;`

It's important to have a space between the two `>` characters, otherwise the compiler won't understand it. (EDIT: I'm talking about the older C++ standard here. This should not be a problem in C++11.)